# Auto enable chrome extension installation

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using Chrome 25.0.1364.152 m and I develop a Chrome Extension. I wanna install it as an external extension and I succeed. The only problem is that I must enable this extension manually. That means I have to enable it every user profile. (I have lots of Chrome user profile on my machine) Is there any way to do this enable work automatically(via preference or something)?

Comment: When extensions are installed they are enabled by default, is that not your case?

Comment: @Sudarshan yeah, this seems a new feature in Chrome 25. extension silent installation is not allowed.